Tmux not able to copy using mouse
I am using iterm and tmux. I have set the mouse support on for the tmux. However, I am still not able to copy any text from tmux using mouse.
without tmux, if I just select the text, and right click on it, it's being selected. However, with tmux it doesn't happen.
following is my tmux conf.
bind r
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf
bind-key h select-pane -L
bind-key j select-pane -D
bind-key k select-pane -U
bind-key l select-pane -R

set -g mouse on
set -g prefix C-s
set -g default-command /bin/zsh
# List of plugins
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible'
set -g @plugin 'catppuccin/tmux'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'
set -g @plugin 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'


set -g @catppuccin_window_left_separator ""
set -g @catppuccin_window_right_separator " "
set -g @catppuccin_window_middle_separator " █"
set -g @catppuccin_window_number_position "right"

set -g @catppuccin_window_default_fill "number"
set -g @catppuccin_window_default_text "#W"

set -g @catppuccin_window_current_fill "number"
set -g @catppuccin_window_current_text "#W"

# set -g @catppuccin_status_modules_right "directory user host session"
set -g @catppuccin_status_modules_right "directory session"
set -g @catppuccin_status_left_separator  " "
set -g @catppuccin_status_right_separator ""
set -g @catppuccin_status_fill "icon"
set -g @catppuccin_status_connect_separator "no"

set -g @catppuccin_directory_text "#{pane_current_path}"

set -g @continuum-restore 'on'

set -g status-position top
set-option -sg escape-time 10
set-option -sg focus-events on

run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'


does it work if u disable all the plugins?

I have the exact same plugins enabled on my intel mac, and it works.

if it's not related to any plugins u can remove them from the question so others can try with a minimal tmux conf which is much easier to debug.

This is how I do it with mouse mode on:

Hold Shift
Select text with the mouse
Release Shift
CTRL+Shift+c

Use CTRL+Shift+v to paste back into the terminal, or the normal CTRL+c to paste into most other applications.
From this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/749259/605343
